# how to get referral web page using Selenium webDrive?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium webDrive for Chrome.

How can i get the referral url ?

meaning the prevues url. the one before the current

I want to compare it to current url.

Comment: Please provide more information of what you mean by "referral url".  The `driver.Url` will get the URL from the browser.  Are you trying to compare that with a url of some link element?

Comment: with the prevues url, the one before the current

Comment: Just do a `driver.Url` before you do the action that sends you off to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store it in a variable and compare it to the present.
I'll have a stub method with various implementation using the getCurrentURL.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Code example:

```
    String previousUrl = driver.Url;
    //Code to navigate to the next page whether that is a navigate or button click

    if (previousUrl == driver.Url)
    {
        //match code goes here
    }
    else
    {
        //failed match code goes here
    }
```

Please also note that depending on your packages there are ones that can determine the hostname fairly easily if you are wondering if you navigated to a completely different site or the same site, but a different page.

If you desire to compare very specific parts of the URL then you probably want to use a regular expression comparison to identify the specific parts.